# Command line calc program and PI constant

Tags: command-line, calculator

I am using `calc` often (from the terminal) and I was wondering if there is a PI constant in there, predefined, somewhere?

Comment: +1 because I like the question. I have spend about 2 hours looking for an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about calc from the apcalc package the constant Pi is defined like this:

```
pi()
```

note, the parentheses are used even though the function does not take any arguments.

not too clear for the GUI desktop calculator,gcalctool, either, which is:
Ctrl+P

Comment: is there a list of those *functions*? :)

Comment: Do not know, Pi being so important in my work I have some experience how it is used in many different calculating tools, calc follows the spreadsheet method.

Answer (score 0):

you also can choose kcalc
there is a scientific - mode in kcalc
there again you can choose mathematical constants
e.g. PI, Euler, golden ratio ...

if you want to tickle more out of PI in own written program
you can use then the library of http://gmplib.org/
this library you can use when compiling with gcc resp. g++

have fun !

Comment: Gnome, the shell I use, also has a graphical scientific calculator. The question was more about the command line program, and was not about programming :) But thanks for sharing this.